# Java Android Generar un documento a partir de una plantilla .docx

Tags: java, android, linux, plugin

Estoy intentando generar un documento gracias al plugin:

 [xdocreport-1.0.4.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/xdocreport/1.0.4)

Digamos que me ha funcionado desde el pc, a raíz de una plantilla generar otra con los datos introducidos en el formulario pero desde el teléfono android no logro hacer que funcione, me imagino que el problema se encuentra en el GeneradorDocumentosService por el toURL...

**Tengo dos clase:**

 - Main.java

 - GeneradorDocumentosService.java

**Mi proyecto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi documento Test.docx dentro de Assets con sus variables con MergeField**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi problema al darle generar el archivo:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la clase **Main.java** tengo esto, código completo [Main.Java](https://github.com/DomingoMG/TemplateDocxAndroid/blob/master/Main.java)

```
public static void generateDocument(String rutaPlantilla, String extension, 
boolean convertirPdf) 
throws IOException, XDocReportException
{

Map<String, Object> variablesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

variablesMap.put("name", name);
variablesMap.put("surname", surname);
variablesMap.put("date", date);

// 2) Create fields metadata to manage lazy loop (#forech velocity)
// for table row.
FieldsMetadata metadata = new FieldsMetadata();
metadata.addFieldAsList("listaNumeros.Numero");
metadata.addFieldAsList("listaNumeros.Cuadrado");
metadata.addFieldAsList("listaNumeros.Raiz");

// Mapa con las variables de tipo imagen. Estas variables contienen el path 
de la imagen
Map<String, String> imagenesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
imagenesMap.put("header_image_logo", "./Logo.png");

GeneradorDocumentosService generadorDocumentosService = new 
GeneradorDocumentosService();
byte[] mergedOutput = 
generadorDocumentosService.generarDocumento(rutaPlantilla,
        TemplateEngineKind.Freemarker, variablesMap, imagenesMap, 
convertirPdf, metadata
);

FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("Faycan_Contract_"+"." 
+extension);
os.write(mergedOutput);
os.flush();
os.close();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

txtNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
txtApellidos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtApellidos);
txtFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);

name = txtNombre.getText().toString();
surname = txtApellidos.getText().toString();
date = txtFecha.getText().toString();

btnGenerar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerar);
btnGenerar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
  try
  {
  generateDocument("file:///android_asset/test.docx", "docx", false);
  } catch (Exception e)
  {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The document could not be 
   generated"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
    }
});
}
```

En la clase **GeneradorDocumentosService.java** tengo esto que podría ser el error, código completo [GeneradorDocumentosService.Java](https://github.com/DomingoMG/TemplateDocxAndroid/blob/master/Main.java)

```
public static InputStream loadDocumentAsStream(String filePath) throws 
IOException
{ 
 URL url = new File(filePath).toURI().toURL();
 InputStream documentAsStream = url.openStream();
 return documentAsStream;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi solución ante este problema es usando el plugin: JWord y indicando la plantilla desde la tarjeta "sdcard" con "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.GetPath()+"/Template.docx", y lo mismo para la salida del fichero...

Haré la comprobación de meterlo en la carpeta "Assets" y llamarlo por "file:///android_asset/template.docx"así no estar la plantilla suelta por el teléfono...